# fatal error while compiling cuda program

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I'm implementing a program by using **dynamic parallelism**. Whenever I'm compiling the code, it is throwing fatal error as follows:

> `ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function 'cudaGetParameterBuffer'`

Compiling as below:

> `nvcc -o dyn_par dyn_par.cu -arch=sm_35`

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cudaGetParameterBuffer` is part of the `cudadevrt` library which you need to specify in your compiler command and specify `--relocatable-device-code` as true

```
nvcc -o dyn_par dyn_par.cu -arch=sm_35 -lcudadevrt --relocatable-device-code true
```

Have a look at the [CUDA Dynamic Parallelism Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUDA_Dynamic_Parallelism_Programming_Guide.pdf) from Nvidia (Page 21 describes the above) for more information